# passing 1 2 23 32 4 returns 4 in max function in python, why?

Tags: python, max, command-line-arguments

My codes

```
def validate():
    if len(sys.argv) > 6:
        print("No more than 5 arguments please")
        exit()

def printArgs():
    print("\nthe arguments are:\n")

    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        print (arg)

def checkDigits():
    biggest = []
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        if arg.isdigit():
            biggest.append(arg)

    if len(biggest)>= 3:
        print("\nthe biggest number passed is: ", max(biggest))
    else:
        print("you did not pass 3 or more numbers")

def main():

    validate()
    printArgs()
    checkDigits()

main()
```

if I pass 1 2 23 32 4, it returns 4 instead of 32 in the "checkDigit" function and I don't know why.  Passing 5 4 3 2 1 returns 5, so am I missing something?

I read another StackOverflow post and think adding key=int to my max function should work, am I right?

```
def checkDigits():
    biggest = []
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        if arg.isdigit():
            biggest.append(arg)

    if len(biggest)>= 3:
        print("\nthe biggest number passed is: ", max(biggest, key=int))
    else:
        print("you did not pass 3 or more numbers")
```

Comment: You're passing strings to `max`. Strings are compared lexicographically.

Comment: @James using `key=int` will return `'32'` (the *string* `32`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function checkDigits, you must append in the "biggest" list the integer number, so change for this:

```py
def checkDigits():
    biggest = []
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        if arg.isdigit():
            biggest.append(int(arg))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are taking the `max` of a list of strings. You need to convert to `int`.

To demonstrate, this is what you're doing:

```
max("1 2 23 32 4".split())
#'4'
```

This is what you should be doing:

```
max(map(int, "1 2 23 32 4".split()))
#32
```

The natural place to update your code is to convert to `int` when you are appending to `biggest`:

```
def checkDigits():
    biggest = []
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        if arg.isdigit():
            biggest.append(int(arg))  #THIS LINE IS CHANGED

    if len(biggest)>= 3:
        print("\nthe biggest number passed is: ", max(biggest))
    else:
        print("you did not pass 3 or more numbers")
```